# Laravel Livewire admin

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, filamentphp

I'm looking into a making an Admin using FilamentPHP library, I love the speed, the fact it uses laravel/livewire and how well it's documented.

One thing that I'm trying to wrap my head around is, say that I build an app with FilamentPHP, I was looking into, if there is an easy way, to spawn an `REST API` or `GRAPHQL` one from the code / database inside the filamentphp structure.

Furthermore, since the laravel app seems to be able to handle channels and events, is there a way to do a `GraphQL Subscription` or `Websocket` so that way, say Mobile App could connect to the filamentphp / laravel backend with live updates?